# How to make items appear in JFrame, in Java Ready to Program1.5

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface

I'm trying to create a game using GUI and borderlayout.My Game will be one of those memory card games that shows cards with numbers on each and then flips them after a certain time. Im also going on the assumption that it doesnt matter that im using a windows emulator because it works for other Java Gui's (second example below) I seem to be having problems making sure that my JFrame is set up properly because nothing appears when I click run. (Just as an aside I'm using Java Ready To Program on a Windows emulator in Ubuntu15.

```java
// The "JavaMemoryGame_Final" class.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.URL;
public class JavaMemoryGame_Final
{
    static JButton btnStart, buttonArray[] = new JButton [12];
    static JTextField nameEnter, quAnswer;
    static JLabel scoreOutput, lblTitle, lblPrompt1, lblPrompt2, arrayImage[] 
        = new JLabel [12], t_fImage, lblInstruct, lblReadyCheck;
    static JRadioButton reallyBad, bad, good, reallyGood;
    static ButtonGroup finalSurvey;
    static AudioClip clap, yess, noo;
    static JList difficulty;
    static DefaultListModel listModel;
    static int randNumGenerator;
    static JFrame start, questions, survey;

    static int score = 0;

    private static void randNumDifficulty()
    {
        //Method to generate random numbers for game...
        int randNumGenerator[] = new int [12];

        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 11 ; i++)
        {
            randNumGenerator [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 12) + 1;
            arrayImage [i] = new JLabel ("" + randNumGenerator [i]);
        }
        //return;
    }

    private static void guiApp()
    {
        //Set Up Frames
        start = new JFrame ("Welcome");
        start.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        questions = new JFrame ("Memry_Game");
        questions.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        survey = new JFrame ("How Was It?");
        survey.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        btnStart = new JButton ("Enter");
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 11 ; i++)
        {
            buttonArray [i] = new JButton ("");
        }

        lblTitle = new JLabel ("Memory Match Game!");
        lblInstruct = new JLabel ("Welcome to the Memory Match Game! " + 
            "Type in your name, choose your time and click start to " + 
            "begin. You'll be given an amount of time (based on the " + 
            "amount you chose) to memorize game card numbers, after " + 
            "the allotted time is up you will have to click them in " + 
            "ascending order and then click submit.");
        lblPrompt1 = new JLabel ("Please enter your first name:");
        lblPrompt2 = new JLabel ("Choose Difficulty:");
        nameEnter = new JTextField ("");
        scoreOutput = new JLabel ("Score: " + score + "/15");
        reallyBad = new JRadioButton ("Really Bad");
        bad = new JRadioButton ("Bad");
        good = new JRadioButton ("Good");
        reallyGood = new JRadioButton ("Really Good");
        lblReadyCheck = new JLabel ("");
        lblReadyCheck.setForeground (Color.green);

        finalSurvey = new ButtonGroup ();
        finalSurvey.add (reallyBad);
        finalSurvey.add (bad);
        finalSurvey.add (good);
        finalSurvey.add (reallyGood);

        //Declare Audio
        URL ebob = JavaMemoryGame_Final.class.getResource ("");
        clap = Applet.newAudioClip (ebob);
        URL bob = JavaMemoryGame_Final.class.getResource ("yes-1.wav");
        yess = Applet.newAudioClip (bob);
        URL tom = JavaMemoryGame_Final.class.getResource ("no-6.wav");
        noo = Applet.newAudioClip (tom);

        //Setup of buttons
        ButtonHandler onClick = new ButtonHandler ();
        btnStart.addActionListener (onClick);
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 11 ; i++)
        {
            buttonArray [i].addActionListener (onClick);
        }

        //set up radio buttons
        finalSurvey = new ButtonGroup ();
        finalSurvey.add (reallyBad);
        finalSurvey.add (bad);
        finalSurvey.add (good);
        finalSurvey.add (reallyGood);

        //Set Up List Model
        listModel = new DefaultListModel ();
        listModel.addElement ("10 seconds");
        listModel.addElement ("15 seconds");
        listModel.addElement ("30 seconds");

        //Set Up List
        difficulty = new JList (listModel);
        difficulty.setVisibleRowCount (1);

        //Declare Panels
        JPanel mainStart = new JPanel (new BorderLayout ());
        mainStart.setForeground (Color.red);

        JPanel mainContent = new JPanel (new BorderLayout ());
        mainContent.setForeground (Color.red);

        JPanel scoreStuff = new JPanel (new BorderLayout ());

        JPanel mainGame = new JPanel (new BorderLayout ());
        mainGame.setBackground (Color.orange);

        JPanel feedbackPanel = new JPanel (new BorderLayout ());
        feedbackPanel.setForeground (Color.blue);

        //Seperate Panels
        mainContent.add (lblPrompt1);
        mainContent.add (nameEnter);

        scoreStuff.add (scoreOutput);
        scoreStuff.add (lblPrompt2);

        //add items to panels
        mainStart.add (lblTitle, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        mainStart.add (lblInstruct, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        mainStart.add (mainContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainStart.add (difficulty, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        mainStart.add (scoreStuff, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        Container contentPane = start.getContentPane ();
        contentPane.add (mainStart);
        Container contentPane1 = questions.getContentPane ();
        contentPane1.add (mainGame);
        Container contentPane2 = survey.getContentPane ();
        contentPane2.add (feedbackPanel);
        start.setSize (600, 450);
        start.setVisible (true);
        questions.setSize (600, 450);
        questions.setVisible (false);
        survey.setSize (600, 450);
        survey.setVisible (false);

    } // Place your code here

    private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            String text = nameEnter.getText ();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable ()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                guiApp ();
            }
        }
        );
    }
} // JavaMemoryGame_Final class
```

```js
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TestFrame
                extends         JFrame
{
        public TestFrame()
        {
                setTitle( "Test Application" );
                setSize( 200, 100 );
                setBackground( Color.gray );

                Panel topPanel = new Panel();
                topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
                getContentPane().add( topPanel );

                // Create a label to look at
                Label labelHello = new Label( "Hello World!" );
                topPanel.add( labelHello, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        }


        // Main program started
        public static void main( String args[] )
        {
                // Create an instance of the test application
                TestFrame mainFrame     = new TestFrame();
                mainFrame.setVisible( true );
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use spaces between parentheses on method signatures as it is used to help distinguish keywords from method calls.

Comment: i fixed that but it still makes no difference in what appears on the JFrame itself when run

Comment: It shouldn't, but the thing is stay consistent with your code style as it is very hard to read when there are sporadically appearing spaces.

Comment: ok thanks i appreciate it